# web.config Vs App.config for Assemblies

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-3.0

I have a web application and in the Web.Config I am adding the assemblies as shown below

```
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

In the .cs file I include the namespaces and use it in my code.

How do I do this in App.config page in a WCF service application?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, right-click References and select Add Reference...

This should take care of everything else for you.

Comment: Doesnt matter, you are still adding references to them.